# Facebook share link is not getting into my application in ios (Previously it working fine)

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am doing autoposting at the time of clicking a button this is the code

```
-(void) autoPost
{
NSString *shareurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",kBOTL_URL_1, @"shr/",[self.Botl stringForKey:@"bid"]];

NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:shareurl,@"link", nil];
NSLog(@"params %@", params);

FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] init];

NSLog(@"FBSESSION %@", session);

if (session.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded || session.state == FBSessionStateOpen )
{

    [[[[iToast makeText:@"Post on wall success"] setGravity:iToastGravityBottom] setDuration:iToastDurationShort]show];
    // even though we had a cached token, we need to login to make the session usable
    [session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                         FBSessionState status,
                                         NSError *error) {
        [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed"
                                     parameters:params
                                     HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                              completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error){
                                  NSLog(@"error-- %@",error);
                              }];
    }];
}
```

it post the url  on facebook wall. but the problem is when we click on that link previously it open my iOS app.

Now it will not open my app, instead of that it opens in browser. Can u please answer this question.

Thanks in advance...